# Selective activation of indexes in Firedac

Tags: delphi, firebird, delphi-xe7, firedac

I'm using *FireDAC* (TFDTable) with *Firebird* database in *Delphi XE7* and I want to activate existing indexes on them **selectively**.

I'm avoiding to set the FireDAC property `IndexesActive` to `True` as the latter activates all existing indexes at once and consumes noticable time. Instead, I'm trying to activate certain indexes individually but in vain.

I noticed that, in order to activate individual indexes, you still need to set `IndexesActive` property to `True`, which doesn't make a lot of sense. I can notice that contradiction even in the help documentation of Delphi where on one hand they say

> To selectively enable and disable data views rather than turning them all on or off at once, use the `Active` property of individual `TFDIndex` objects.

and on the other hand

> In general, the view is maintained if the dataset's `IndexesActive` is `True`.

Can anyone point out a way of activating indexes individually in FireDAC?

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone point out a way of activating indexes individually in Firedac?

Based on my observations, I'm not sure there is any point in that, because there
seems to be another way of minimising the delay activating or switching between indexes.

I have a FDQuery that retrieves 20k 60-column rows from a server. It has 5 defined indexes and is connected to a DBGrid.

All the operations I'm going to mention are surrounded by calls to FDQuery1.DisableControls & .EnableControls and code which records the time the operation takes in milliseconds.

1. The first call to FDQuery1.Open takes approximately 300ms, regardless of whether FDQuery1.IndexesActive is set to True beforehand or not. After calling .Open, FDQuery1.RecordCount is 50 so obviously it has not retreived the entire result set at this point.
2. Then, doing FDQuery.Last; FDQuery1.First takes about 620ms.
3. Setting IndexesActive to True after opening FDQuery1 takes ~0ms.
4. Then, activating a specific index by name

   ```
   procedure TForm1.UseIndex(const AName : String);
   var
     Index : TFDIndex;
     T1 : Integer;
   begin
     T1 := GetTickCount;
     FDQuery1.DisableControls;
     Index := FDQuery1.Indexes.IndexByName(AName);
     Index.Active := True;
     FDQuery1.IndexName := AName;
     FDQuery1.EnableControls;
     Caption := IntToStr(GetTickCount - T1);
   end;
   ```

   takes between 50 and 200ms, apparently depending on how the sorted order
   of the data rows differs from their physical (retrieval) order.
5. Restarting the project and omitting step 2, the first time an index is activated as per step 4, it takes about 630ms.

Based on the above, the responsiveness of the GUI seems to be improved by using
code like this:

```
T1 := GetTickCount;
FDQuery1.IndexesActive := True;
FDQuery1.DisableControls;
FDQuery1.Active := True;
FDQuery1.First;
FDQuery1.Last;
FDQuery1.EnableControls;
Caption := IntToStr(FDQuery1.RecordCount) + ' ' + IntToStr(GetTickCount - T1);
```

before the form is shown.  The recorded time is around 1000ms but is hardly
noticeably because the form is not yet on screen.

Once that has been done, activating any one the indexes takes at most 300ms.

Comment: i noticed that your using a FDQuery in your case above where your indexes are actually "client" indexes not maintained by the database. In my case, i'm using TFDTable and trying to activate indexes that are actually created by my Firebird database.

Comment: @Johny:  It would have helped if you had mentioned the fact that you're using an FDTable as you seemed to be talking about FireDAC indexes, not server-side ones.  Anyway, what's the point using server-side indexes if the FireDAC dataset can construct its own indexes on the fly?

Comment: @MartnA: Activating client side indexes on FireDac consumes far more time than activating server side indexes. On a table having around 1 million record, activating a single database-based index consumes 1 second, while it takes around 20 seconds to activate a client side index on FireDac. Note that i'm trying to migrate an application which was based on BDE tables to FireDac.

Comment: @Johny:  You're not seriously suggesting that your retrieve all 1 million records to the client when you open your FDTable, are you?  Anyway, I give up - you are revealing one by one details of your situation which ought to have been in your q in the first place, so I've voted to close it.

Comment: Take it easy @MartynA, i'm just answering your questions here. The fact that i didn't reveal the entire story of my case doesn't take away anything from the original question that i raised first. Regardless of what im actually trying to acheive, I see a design contradiction in FireDAC's behavior as far as index activation is concerned.

Comment: that line **FDQuery1.RecordCount is 50 so obviously it has not retrieved the entire result set at this point.** helped me solve an ugly bug, thank you